# Pouvons-nous être prévenus quand un de nos messages est édité ? Could we be alerted when our posts are edited?

Tags: feature-request, editing, notifications

I am somewhat of a perfectionist, and I sometimes go over my old posts to see if they have been edited (and try and learn from that). It would be much easier if it were possible to be alerted (via global SE inbox) to edits of your posts.

---

Je suis un peu perfectionniste sur les bords, et des fois je passe en revue mes anciens messages pour voir s'ils ont été édités (et j'espère apprendre quelque chose au passage). Ce serait beaucoup plus facile si nous étions prévenus des modifications portées à nos messages (grâce à la boîte aux lettres globale).

Comment: [This feature has been requested on the main meta site.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/notify-us-when-one-of-our-posts-is-edited)

[Cette fonctionnalité a été demandée sur le site méta principal.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/notify-us-when-one-of-our-posts-is-edited)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a notification, but the tab "responses" of the user panel has a section "revisions" which shows the revisions made to your answer (and perhaps questions).